# Firefox Android add-on does not allow Button?

Tags: android, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I made a Firefox extension using the Add-on SDK with a [Button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_action). This works fine in the Desktop Firefox: button shows up and it works. But when I push the add-on to Firefox for Android using jpm-mobile and ADB (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Mobile_development) for what that means), the button is missing.
Are Buttons not supported in Android for Firefox? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so, in order to do it on android you have to use `NativeWindow` and add item to the menu: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Firefox_for_Android/API/NativeWindow/menu

Comment: Hmm that would have to do if it really isn't possible. I just find it frustrating that the documentation doesn't state it.

Comment: The modules supported on Firefox for Android are listed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Mobile_development#Module_Compatibility. And of the ui modules only the ui/id low-level module is supported, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, this is probably everything possible in Firefox for Android Add-ons:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Firefox_for_Android/API

An alternative to a toolbar button could be a URL bar action.

Comment: I heard we can use java bits via jni, i havent looked into it but once i leanr ill show you how :)